# Django complains that django.contrib.gis.measure.Distance is not a valid model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Environment details:

- Ubuntu GNOME 14.04
- Python 2.7.6 (using a virtualenv)
- Django 1.7 (inside the virtualenv)
- Eclipse Kepler SR2 (build id 20140224-0627)
- PyDev 3.8.0.201409251235

I have the following in a model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance
...

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    distance = models.ForeignKey(Distance)
    ...
```

The model is located in `/home/user/workspace/DjangoProject/MyApp/models/mymodel.py`.  In the `models` folder, I have an `__init__.py` which imports `MyModel`:

`from MyApp.models.mymodel import MyModel`

When I try to run the server (`python manage.py runserver`) or sync the models to the database (`python manage.py syncdb`), I get the following error:

`AssertionError: ForeignKey(<class 'django.contrib.gis.measure.Distance'>) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string u'self'`

I checked `django/contrib/gis/measure.py` and the `Distance` model inside appears to be a valid model. **Why does Django think that `Distance` is not a valid model?**

Comment: why do you have a models folder in the app file?  I don't think I've ever seen that.  Do you get the same result when you move mymodel.py into the myapp folder?

Comment: @ChrisHawkes from what I've read, this seems to be the standard way to decompose a large models.py into multiple files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance` is not a Model, it is just a class that extends MeasureBase that extends object.

```
class MeasureBase(object):¬                                                                                                                       
   STANDARD_UNIT = None¬
   ALIAS = {}¬
   UNITS = {}¬
   LALIAS = {}¬
```

So, "Why does Django think that Distance is not a valid model?" - because it isn't a model. Models in Django are created by extending `models.Model`.